# Specifying permisions with icacls

Tags: file-permissions, icacls

I want to allocate read only permission to "Everyone" on an empty folder so that the users are not allowed to change the folder name.
However I want "Everyone" to be able to create/modify/delete files in the folder.

say the folder is called /fred/myfolder

I've tried

```
icacls /fred /grant Everyone:(OI)R
```

and

```
icacls /fred/myfolder /grant Everyone:(CI)R
icacls /fred/myfolder /grant Everyone:(OI)F
```

and various combinations to no avail.
The documentation/my knowledge isn't great.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.
I needed

```
icacls /fred /grant Everyone:(OI)R
```

Then i just needed

```
icacls /fred/myfolder /grant Everyone:(OI)(CI)(OI)F
```

These were the combinations that I found very useful:

```
(NP) This Folder Only.
(OI) This folder and files.
(CI) This folder and subfolders.
(OI)(CI) This folder, subfolders, and files.
(OI)(CI)(IO) Subfolders and files only.
(CI)(IO) Subfolders only.
(OI)(IO) Files only.
```